# Heroku - how to start job worker (delayed job)?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, delayed-job

I have some miniapp that use delayed_job. On my localhost everything works fine, but when I deploy my app to Heroku and click on the link that should be executed by delayed_job, so nothing happen, the "task" is just saved into the table `delayed_job`.

[In this article on heroku blog](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/delayed-job) is written, that the task from `delayed_job` table is executed, when is run this command **rake jobs:work**.

But how can I run this command? Where should be the command placed? In the code, or from terminal console?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are running the Cedar stack, run the following from the terminal console:

```
heroku run rake jobs:work
```

If you are running the older stacks (Bamboo, Aspen, etc.):

```
heroku rake jobs:work
```

see: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rake

According to the `delayed_job` [documentation](https://github.com/tobi/delayed_job), you can also start a worker programmatically:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../config/environment'

Delayed::Worker.new.start
```

Comment: yes, this works me. But how can I run this task automatically from my app?

Comment: what about when you want to start a worker when something goes into the queue? do you have to have a worker that is running the whole time, and picking off tasks from the queue? isn't that problematic with Heroku restarting dynos once every day..

Comment: If you'd like to have a worker that automatically runs tasks as they are put into the queue, then you need to put the delayed_job command into your Procfile as a new process and add at least 1 worker dyno to your application on Heroku.

Comment: Is this 'heroku run rake jobs:work' works on the heroku machines?. Probably yes, I type this and I do not need to do anything right?. worker dyno watches 24/7.  In local you have to type 'rake jobs:work' to watch i guess. But even though I dont run 'rake jobs:work' it works.

Answer (score 10):

You should use a Procfile to scpecify the commands for your dynos.
For example you would have something like this in your Procfile:

appDir/Procfile

```
web:     bundle exec rails server -p $PORT 
worker:  bundle exec rake jobs:work
```

To use this on your development machine, you should use Foreman, it's all explained at the docs.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile

Answer (score 1):

In our case we're only running a delayed job once a month, so didn't want to have a worker dyno running constantly.

To solve this we queue up the job (with `.delayed`) and then use the [Heroku platform API](https://github.com/heroku/platform-api) to spawn `rake jobs:workoff` in a one-off worker. The API call returns relatively quickly.

```
PlatformAPI.connect_oauth(ENV["YOUR_HEROKU_KEY"]).dyno.create(ENV["YOUR_HEROKU_APP_NAME"],{command: 'rake jobs:workoff'})
```